# 2 Datatables to 1

Tags: datatable

Let's say i have Datatable1 that has "Colum1" , "colum2"
and another table, Datatable2 with "Colum3" , "colum4"

I need to create Datatable3 that will contain all the columns "Colum1" , "colum2", "Colum3" , "colum4"

I need something smart, like the DefaultView.ToTable() method that does it for one table.

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to join the rows?  How do you plane to determine what row from Datatable1 matches Datatable2?

Comment: Both tables?  Which column in each table is the primary key?

Comment: Database? Memory? Ado? Excel? JDBC? Access? Word? Provide at least some tags to specify the technologies you are using.

Comment: Datatable and DefaultView.ToTable are from ADO.NET - looks like a request to combine two .NET Datatables - no SQL or particular DB

Comment: Yes, but that is us assuming stuff...

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention any language or DB server type, here's something that might work (not tested really) on SQL Server 2005:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (col1 <type>, col2 <type>, col3 <type>, col4 <type>)
INSERT INTO #temp
(
    SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t2.Column3, t2.Column4
    FROM Datatable1 t1 INNER JOIN Datatable2 t2 ON t2.<PrimaryKeyField> = t1.<PrimaryKeyField>

    UNION

    SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t2.Column3, t2.Column4
    FROM Datatable2 t2 INNER JOIN Datatable1 t1 ON t1.<PrimaryKeyField> = t2.<PrimaryKeyField>
)

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry i meant the .net object Datatable. I would like to do it in the c# code, not in the DB level.